# Setting comments in method from protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

So I have a protocol setup in swift, and I'd like to add additional information in the methods (like comments) to the classes that use it

Currently its created using

```
protocol ImportProtocol {
    var moc : NSManagedObjectContext { get set }
    
    init(viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext)
    // Various methods which aren't an issue
    func importDIM()
}

extension ImportProtocol {
    // Default implementation of the various methods above
    // No implementation of init or importDIM methods
}
```

Is it possible to make it to that when it adds the importDIM methods it provides some content on the method to begin with? Currently the method is blank but I'd like to make it add with

```
func importDIM() {
     let dim = addDIM()
     // Stage 1
}
```

Comment: Please focus on only one question at a time. Btw for your first, you cannot define values in protocols.

Comment: annoying but I figured that would be the answer. My main focus is the other question

Comment: Ok I answered your second question and removed my close flag

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this, you have to define a protocol with your methods, and an protocol extension where you can set computed vars and methods with code.

Example :

```
protocol ImportProtocol {

}

extension ImportProtocol {
    func importDIM() {
        let dim = addDIM()
        // Stage 1
    }
}
```

And then your classes that implements the protocol have also the base methods with code.

Some more documentation about that with more example :
https://cocoacasts.com/how-to-create-an-abstract-class-in-swift

Comment: I’m not sure that’s really going to do what I want. I have an unknown number of variables crated in each class so can’t really do it in the protocol that I can tell. I was just looking to see if I’m there was an easier way as it’s a lot of copy paste when I use the same comment headings in each file

Comment: Btw my answer answer your question.. This is the way to achieve what you want.